# copiar texto do pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame

Galera, já tentei de tudo e não consigo copiar um texto de uma janela do Pygame. O código é o seguinte:

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.font.init()
font1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 150)
text = font1.render("Alô Mundo", True, (255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(text, (0, 200))
pygame.display.flip()

def principal():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               return
        pygame.time.delay(30)

principal()
```

Eu gostaria de copiar o Alo Mundo que aparecerá na tela do pygame. Alguém tem alguma sugestão ?

Comment: o que vc quis dizer com `copiar` ?

Comment: conseguir passar o mouse por cima do texto e copia-lo, como se faz normalmente com qualquer texto

Comment: Entendo não ser possível, pois o texto é renderizado como imagem. Caso seja possível, será surpresa para mim. Alguém?

Comment: exato, você sabe se é posssivel com tkinter ?

Comment: Sim, “printando” o texto como `label` acredito ser possível.

Comment: mas não tem como copiar o texto de um label, tem ?

Comment: Respondendo no post

Answer (score 0):

Baseado no que conversamos nos comentários.

### Pygame

No `pygame` não creio ser possível...

### Tkinter

Tem sim como copiar o `label` no `tkinter`, porém **não** é o padrão.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Text(master, height=1, borderwidth=0)
w.insert(1.0, "Copia este texto!!!")
w.pack()
w.configure(state="normal")  # o default de state é `disable`
mainloop()
```

**Update**

Todas as pessoas apontam para um `text entry`. **Porém** se vc realmente quiser fazer com `Label`, embora não seja intuitivo, você pode criar uma função que captura o texto quando o label é clicado.

Veja abaixo

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

def pega_texto(event):
    lbl = event.widget
    master.clipboard_clear()
    master.clipboard_append(lbl.cget("text"))
    master.update()  # mantém no clipboard mesmo fechandpo a janela.


lbl = "Hello World!"
w = Label(master, text=lbl)
w.bind("<Button-1>", pega_texto)
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: mas isso já é um widget de texto, não tem como copiar o label ?